# How to generate a link in JSP to JSP file located into WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I did : /WEB-INF/index.jsp.
Into index.jsp, I have a links to another .jsp's files like about.jsp ...etc
But how to generate this link ?
href="about.jsp" doesn't work, it is normal because folder WEB-INF is protected by tomcat.

Comment: The 1st dupe explains the JSF approach and the 2nd dupe explains the "plain vanilla" JSP/Servlet approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context path.

You link will be like `href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/about.jsp`.

Comment: i'am do it but not work, it give to me error 404